# Change tab indicator color in actionbar

Tags: android

I know this question was asked many times before, but I tried all solutions and nothing is working. So I've decided to follow official documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

I've made file themes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
        parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar tabs styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTabs"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
        <!-- tab indicator -->
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

actionbar_background is just simple shape with solid fill and it's working.
However indicator is still blue:
actionbar_tab_indicator - this is file generated from http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/
I've also copy-pasted generated images to drawable folder. First issue was 9-patch files were somehow wrong, but I've managed to manually fix them. 

I'm setting theme in AndroidManifest.xml: android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"

I've also tried solutions for changing color programatically, but it doesn't work as intended. Instead of being small rectangle it's stretched to fit whole tab.

Any solution (programatically or in xml) working in latest android studio will be great. But it must look just like the orginal tab, but with other color - in my case red.

Regards

Comment: whats your minSDK version?

Comment: @MounirElfassi It's 15. (Android 4.0.3)

Comment: Are you using any library for the indicator?

Comment: Nope, I just want to use ordinary TabHost (with fragments) and only change indicator color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always found it easiest to use the tools from the Android Asset Studio, since I'm not particularly graphically inclined. This tool in particular is very relevant to what you're trying to accomplish: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/
. The full suite of tools can be found at  http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/
. Just choose the colors/styles you want, download the zip file, and copy/paste the files into your project. Then in your AndroidManifest.xml file, reference whichever 'Style name' you choose in the generator (the first text box you filled in on the website) in the activity that contains your ActionBar. So for instance if you called your style 'Custom_action_bar' in the generator, you would add it to your activity as follows:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.company.appname.ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/somename"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Custom_action_bar">
    <!--the above line is all you need to add-->
</activity>
```

Comment: http://android-holo-colors.com/ this saved my day, thanks! Although FAQ didn't exactly said this I combined it with @AliMephpour answer and together it worked! Huge amount of files, but it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
<style name="MyActionBarTabs"  
              parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>

</style>
```

because of your `parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"` for `CustomActionBarTheme`

Comment: Just checked it out. No difference.

Comment: So perhaps your selector with problem, you should attch the selector xml

Comment: This changes the entire tab's background. how do you change the indicator's color alone?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, define one selector in drawable folder (tab_indicator.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/background_tab_selected" />

<item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@drawable/background_tab_unselected" />

</selector>
```

@drawable/background_tab_selected and @drawable/background_tab_unselected are nine-patch images that indicates selected and unselected tab state respectively.

**Note:** The scalable area of background_tab_selected nine-patch image should only contains pixels match with normal background. like this: 
[image] (I mean left and top nine-patch indicators)

then in your onCreate() of your activity, find the TabWidget object and set their background:

```
final TabWidget tabs = (TabWidget) findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);

tabs.getChildTabViewAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_indicator);

tabs.getChildTabViewAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_indicator);

tabs.getChildTabViewAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_indicator);

tabs.setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider);
```

also you could set divider drawable via setDividerDrawable() method.

Hope that help.

Comment: I already tried identical solution. setBackgroundResource, in my case, stretches 9-patch to a whole tab instead of drawing small indicator (like the blue one).

Comment: This code works fine for me. you can check the application at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tv.clippit.android and see how it looks like.

Note: The scalable area of background_tab_selected nine-patch image should only contains pixels match with normal background. please see the embedded image in my answer (top and left nine-patch indicators)

Comment: I tried your image, here's a result (4th tab without setBackgroundResource to show a difference): http://imgur.com/49Wd1Wy

Answer (score 0):

Changing the actionBar tab indicator color is difficult, instead you can use SlidingTabLayout with which you can change the indicator color dynamically too, also you can change the height of the indicator.

To get the **SlidingTabLayout** class (& the widget) import the sample project in the android studio:

1. [**SlidingTabBasic**](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html): for a constant color of the indicator throughout.
2. [**SlidingTabBasic**](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsColors/index.html): for dynamic tab indicator color.

In the slidingTabLayout, there are various options to customize tabs, indicator, and its text.

Use this in your project and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

In your .xml file, you can use the following code to change the height of tabIndicator.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:background="#001e8b"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabTextColor="@android:color/darker_gray"`
    />
```